# Send AJAX data while adding MANUAL line breaks

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxform

I am fetiching data from a form and send it out as a mail. This works fine so far, but currently the result appears on one line and I would love to have a line break between these two rows.

So insted:

```
User: Max Mustermann Recipient: Karl Gunter
```

it should read

```
User: Max Mustermann
Recipient: Karl Gunter
```

I have tried `\r\n` as well as `<br>` but nothing changed. What am I doing wrong?

```
$("#submit").on("click", function () {
    var user = encodeURIComponent("User: " + $("#username").val() + "\r\n");
    var recipient = encodeURIComponent("Recipient: " + $("#recipient").val() + "\r\n");

    $.ajax({
        url: "/SendMail",
        type: "post",
        data: "subject=Test" + "&body=" + user + recipient,
    }).done(function (response) {  ... });
});
```

Comment: Try to use `%0D%0A` instead of `\r\n`, where `\r = %0D` and
`\n = %0A`. Do not wrap these special signs with the encode function.

Comment: var user = encodeURIComponent("User: " + $("#username").val()) + "%0D%0A";

Comment: @IhorVyspiansky  You mean like this? Does not change anything :-(

Comment: I've tried this thing locally, but not via codepen https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/poevWaj (just to show the code). And my browser has opened Gmail with two lines separated with line break.

Comment: I see. Than it might be a problem just on our end with Outlook again (the worst mail client...)

Answer (score 0):

You're the one adding the line breaks so you know they're safe. Does it work to not encode the line breaks?

```
var user = "User: " + encodeURIComponent($("#username").val()) + "\r\n";
var recipient = "Recipient: " + encodeURIComponent($("#recipient").val()) + "\r\n";
```

Or change `\r\n` to an HTML break.